# OPENING PAGE Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /home/mywebsite/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 141

Tags: php, function, image-processing, youtube

I'm getting an error when I try to access my my page or home page

THIS LINE 140: $entry = simplexml_load_string( $result );

THIS LINE 141: $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

```
    $desc = (mb_strlen(strip_tags($media->group->description), 'UTF-8')>350) ? mb_substr($media->group->description, 0, 350, 'UTF-8').'...' : strip_tags($media->group->description);

    $desc_yt = "<strong>youtube.com</strong> - ".$desc;
    $title_yt = $media->group->title;
    $image_yt = 'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/'.$id_yt.'/hqdefault.jpg';

    $return['id_youtube']=$id_yt;
    $return['url']=$youtube;
    $return['title']=$title_yt;
    $return['image']=$image_yt;
    $return['description']=$desc_yt;

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: what does the result contain?

Comment: Its a youtube video , some times i get the page show but mostly not showing and i see the error :'( 

Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /home/mywebsite/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 141

Comment: Error when i getting youtube video infos.